# How to convert a data of type LPTSTR to HWND?

Tags: c++

How to convert a data of type `LPTSTR` to `HWND`?

i tried: `example`

```cpp
LPTSTR hwnd         = L"0x000511E8";
HWND   window_hwnd  = (HWND)hwnd;
```

But the value on `window_hwnd`  is not the same as before, and I cant find the window by utilizing this value.

Comment: Parse the string to hex value, and set this value to a `HWND` pointer.

Comment: Would something like `window_hwnd = std::wcstoll(hwnd, nullptr, 16 /* Or maybe 0 */);` work for you? (If you want to make sure `hwnd` is valid don't set arg 2 of `wcstoll` to `nullptr`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean: How to convert a string to a HWND value?
That can be done like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::wstring hwnd_str{ L"0x000511E8" };    // to show std::wstring :)
    auto value = std::stoull(hwnd_str, nullptr, 16); // convert from hex (base 16) to unsigned long long (needed for HWND conversion next line)
    HWND window_hwnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(value);
}
```

Comment: Technically, you would need `std::stoull()` only if you are compiling for 64bit, `std::stoul()` would suffice for 32bit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Would this do? :) https://godbolt.org/z/6fW76TosP